# Number of loggers used

Tags: java, log4j, logging

I'm working on a very large java application with log4j, and I was wondering if there is a way to extract in runtime the number of active loggers? Or what are the existing loggers in the application?
My end goal is to get a list of all loggers and change their level in runtime.
Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
Enumeration allLoggers = Logger.getRootLogger()
.getLoggerRepository()
.getCurrentLoggers();
```

Then iterate over allLoggers.

Comment: Is there a reason you do `.getRootLogger().getLoggerRepository()` twice?

Comment: Is it correct that you are calling `getRootLogger().getLoggerRepository()` twice?

Answer (score 0):

to get the loggers use one of these

```
Logger rootLogger = LogManager.getRootLogger(); //To get the Root Logger
Enumeration e = LogManager.getCurrentLoggers(); //To get an enumerated list of loggers
rootLogger.getName();                           //To get the logger by name
rootLogger.getEffectiveLevel().toString();      //To get the effective level of the current logger
logger.getParent();                             //Get the ccurrent loggers' parent
//To set a new level for a particular Logger
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("TestLogger");
L    evel lev = Level.toLevel("DEBUG");
```

to set use this:

```
logger.setLevel(lev);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can simply use the `LogManager.getCurrentLoggers()` to return a Logger `Enumeration` .Loop through it and set the `Logger` 's level by setLevel()

```
for (Enumeration<Logger> loggerEnumeratin = LogManager.getCurrentLoggers() ;loggerEnumeratin.hasMoreElements() ;){
            Logger logger = loggerEnumeratin.nextElement();
            logger.setLevel(Level.ERROR);
}
```