# What is getCurrentLoggers's analog in log4j2

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j, log4j2

How can i get all loggers used used in log4j2? In log4j i could use getCurrentLoggers like described here: [Number of loggers used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169578/number-of-loggers-used)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

looks like  i've found the way:

```
File configFile = new File("c:\\my_path\\log4j2.xml");
LoggerContext loggerContext = Configurator.initialize("my_config", null, configFile.toURI());
Configuration configuration = loggerContext.getConfiguration();
Collection<LoggerConfig> loggerConfigs = configuration.getLoggers().values();
```

Answer (score 6):

get all loggers used in log4j2:

```
LoggerContext logContext = (LoggerContext) LogManager
                .getContext(false);
Map<String, LoggerConfig> map = logContext.getConfiguration()
                .getLoggers();
```

Attention:

use org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext

not org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.LoggerContext

Comment: With 2.6.2, there is no `LoggerContext.getConfiguration()`

Comment: Use like         org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext logContext = (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext) LogManager
                .getContext(false);

Comment: @zhukunqian No, that's essentially the same and can still result in ```Cannot cast 'org.apache.logging.log4j.simple.SimpleLoggerContext' to 'org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext'```

Answer (score 4):

YuriR's answer is incomplete in that it does not point that **LoggerConfig** objects are returned, not **Logger**. This is the fundamental difference between Log4j1 and Log4j2 - Loggers cannot be dirrectly manipulated in Log4j2. See [Log4j2 Architecture](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/architecture.html) for details.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running in a web app, you may have multiple `LoggerContext`s.
Please take a look at how `LoggerConfig`s are exposed via JMX in the [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.jmx.Server](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/xref/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/jmx/Server.html) class.

Answer (score 0):

```
LoggerContext ctx = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
Collection<? extends Logger> loggers = ctx.getLoggers();
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Comment: Note that the LoggerContext being casted to is the one for log4j-core - the actual implementation. Although unlikely, Log4j makes no guarantees that these implementation classes won't change from release to release.  Also note the javadoc comment for that method: "Whether this collection is a copy of the underlying collection or not is undefined. Therefore, modify this collection at your own risk." In the current code you will get a copy.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to note that LoggerConfig objects are being returned by getLoggers() and NOT the loggers themselves. As vacant78 pointed out, this is only good for setting the configuration for loggers that have yet to be instantiated. If you already have a bunch of loggers already instantiated, changing the configuration using this method does no good.

For example, to change the level of logging at runtime, refer to this link, which utilizes an undocumented API within Apache (no surprise there) that will change all your currently instantiated logger levels: [Programmatically change log level in Log4j2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23434252/programmatically-change-log-level-in-log4j2/23846361)