# Replace Inline Images in PDF with pdfbox

Tags: java, image, pdfbox

I need to find the (raster) images in a pdf file and resize them
(to change their resolution).

My code is based on the example PrintImageLocations.  For the part
that works, I extend PDFStreamEngine and do special processing for the
"Do" operator:

- I get the original PDImageXObject using the first parameter of the
  operator and the resources.
- then I create a BufferedImage from that and work on it to change the
  number of pixels.
- then I create a new PDImageXObject from the BufferedImage via
  LosslessFactory
- finally I put the new object in the page resources using the
  original object's name

I try to do something similar for inline images and I arrive at the
point where I have a BufferedImage, but I don't know how to use it to
replace the original inline image.

It would also be ok to replace the inline image with a XObject, but
again, I don't know how to substitute the two...

Below is my code; the interesting part is the function "processOperator".

```
// WIP!
// find raster images inside a pdf
// if their resolution is more than 900dpi
// then resize them
// reducing the resolution to 200dpi

// NB bug: fails on pdf files with more than one page
// ...DEBUG ScratchFileBuffer:516 - ScratchFileBuffer not closed!
// also fails on pdf with included pdf
// (e.g. latex \includegraphics{x.pdf})

// # to compile:
// apt install libpdfbox2-java
// export CLASSPATH=.:/usr/share/java/pdfbox2.jar:/usr/share/java/commons-logging.jar
// javac Resampleimages.java
// # to run:
// java Resampleimages x.pdf

// see
// https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/examples.html
// https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.11/javadocs/

import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSBase;
import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSName;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.PDXObject;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.form.PDFormXObject;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.PDImage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.PDImageXObject;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.PDInlineImage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.util.Matrix;
import org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.DrawObject;
import org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.Operator;
import org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDResources;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.LosslessFactory;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Color;

import org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.state.Concatenate;
import org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.state.Restore;
import org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.state.Save;
import org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.state.SetGraphicsStateParameters;
import org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.state.SetMatrix;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;


public class ReplaceBigImages extends PDFStreamEngine
{
    private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(ReplaceBigImages.class);

    public ReplaceBigImages() throws IOException
    {
        addOperator(new Concatenate());
        addOperator(new DrawObject());
        addOperator(new SetGraphicsStateParameters());
        addOperator(new Save());
        addOperator(new Restore());
        addOperator(new SetMatrix());
    }

    public static PDDocument document;

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException
    {
        if( args.length != 1 )
        {
            usage();
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                document = PDDocument.load(new File(args[0]));
                ReplaceBigImages printer = new ReplaceBigImages();

                int pageNum = 0;
                for( PDPage page : document.getPages() )
                {
                    pageNum++;
                    log.info( "Processing page: " + pageNum );
                    printer.processPage(page);
                }
            }
            finally {
                if( document != null )
                    {
                        document.save(args[0].replace(".pdf", "_test.pdf"));
                        document.close();
                    }
            }

        }
    }

    protected void processOperator( Operator operator, List<COSBase> operands) throws IOException
    {
        String operation = operator.getName();
        // log.debug(String.format("Operator %s", operation));
        if( "Do".equals(operation) ) {
            log.debug("### Found Do operator");
            COSName objectName = (COSName) operands.get( 0 );
            PDXObject xobject = getResources().getXObject( objectName );
            // log.debug(String.format("%s isa %s", objectName, xobject.getClass().getSimpleName()));

            if( xobject instanceof PDImageXObject)
            {
                log.debug(String.format("Looking at %s (%s)", objectName.getName(), xobject));
                PDImageXObject image = (PDImageXObject)xobject;

                BufferedImage scaledImage = changeImageResolution(image);
                if (scaledImage != null) {
                    log.debug(String.format("Replacing with %s", scaledImage));
                    PDImageXObject replacement_img = LosslessFactory.createFromImage(document, scaledImage);
                    PDPage currentPage = getCurrentPage();
                    PDResources resources = currentPage.getResources();
                    resources.put(objectName, replacement_img);
                }

            }else if(xobject instanceof PDFormXObject)
            {
                PDFormXObject form = (PDFormXObject)xobject;
                showForm(form);
            }
        } else if  ("BI".equals(operation)) {
            PDPage currentPage = getCurrentPage();
            log.debug("### Found BI operator");
            PDResources resources = currentPage.getResources();
            PDInlineImage image = new PDInlineImage(operator.getImageParameters(),
                                                    operator.getImageData(),
                                                    resources);
            BufferedImage scaledImage = changeImageResolution(image);
            if (scaledImage != null) {
                log.debug(String.format("Replacing with %s", scaledImage));
                PDImageXObject replacement_img = LosslessFactory.createFromImage(document, scaledImage);
                // ARGH!!! How do I replace the inline image???
                resources.add(replacement_img, "pippo");
                // operator.setImageParameters(scaledImage???)
                // operator.setImageData(scaledImage???)
            }

        } else {
            super.processOperator( operator, operands);
        }
    }


    protected BufferedImage changeImageResolution( PDImage image)
        throws IOException
    {
        int imageWidth = image.getWidth();
        int imageHeight = image.getHeight();

        Matrix ctmNew = getGraphicsState().getCurrentTransformationMatrix();
        float imageXScale = Math.abs(ctmNew.getScalingFactorX());
        float imageYScale = Math.abs(ctmNew.getScalingFactorY());

        float resolution = imageWidth / ( imageXScale / 72 );
        String stencil = "";
        if (image.isStencil()) {
            stencil = " (stencil)";
        }

        // TODO: take into consideration the size at which this file is included by TeX
        log.debug("size: ("+imageWidth+","+imageHeight+")@("+imageXScale+","+imageYScale+") resolution = "+resolution+stencil);

        // if ( resolution > 899f ) {
        if ( resolution > 200f ) {

            // what do the following two lines mean???
            BufferedImage bImage = new BufferedImage(imageWidth,
                                                     imageHeight,
                                                     BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            if (image.isStencil()) {
                log.warn("Is stencil; painting black.");
                bImage = image.getStencilImage(Color.black);
            } else {
                bImage = image.getImage();
            }

            int desiredResolution = 200;
            float xFactor = (imageXScale / 72) * desiredResolution / imageWidth;
            float yFactor = (imageYScale / 72) * desiredResolution / imageHeight;
            log.info("Scaling x to "+xFactor);
            int dWidth = (int) (xFactor * imageWidth);
            int dHeight = (int) (yFactor * imageHeight);
            // the image type is from
            // https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.awt.image.
            log.debug(String.format("Destination: %d x %d [%s]",
                                    dWidth,
                                    dHeight,
                                    bImage.getType()));
            BufferedImage scaledImage = new BufferedImage(dWidth,
                                                          dHeight,
                                                          bImage.getType());
            Graphics2D graphics2D = scaledImage.createGraphics();
            graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
                                        RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
            graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,
                                        RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
            graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                                        RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            graphics2D.drawImage(bImage, 0, 0, dWidth, dHeight, null);
            graphics2D.dispose();

            // see https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.11/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/graphics/image/PDImageXObject.html#createFromByteArray-org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument-byte:A-java.lang.String-
            return scaledImage;
        }
        return null;
    }


    private static void usage()
    {
        System.err.println( "Usage: java " + ReplaceBigImages.class.getName() + " <input-pdf>" );
    }

}
```

Comment: What you could do is to create a PDImageXObject with your new image, then get the raw stream and assign these bytes to setImageData(). Also make sure to use the same filters but with the short names (e.g. FLATE_DECODE_ABBREVIATION instead of FLATE_DECODE). Or use the decoded stream and remove all the filters from the target dictionary (file will be bigger, but might be a way to test to see that "something" works)

Comment: What could help a little bit is the code PDInlineImageTest.java, search for this file in the source code download. This creates an uncompressed image totally from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

With (a lot of) help from Tilman Hausherr (details [here](https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/3655151dcd2f3156e4177ad21eecf42bef9081bdba9b0d5a69598003@%3Cusers.pdfbox.apache.org%3E)) I think I have a piece of code that resizes both InlineImages and XObjects.
The approach in the code below is:

- extend PDFStreamEngine and process all operators,
- when I find an Inline Image, save away its transformation matrix
- after finishing with the operators, I parse the page into tokens
- and scan through the tokens
- when I find the BI operator
- I use the transformation matrix (saved before)
- and generate a new image,
- then I substitute the BI token with the new image

Here is the code:

```
package it.sissa.medialab.pdfimages;

// Find raster images inside a pdf
// if their resolution is outside of a given threshold
// then resize them
// reducing the resolution to a given target resolution.

// If the pdf will be included inside another pdf
// (as with TeX \includegraphics)
// one can provide a --scale factor

// Usage
// -----
// java -Dlog4j.configurationFile=/tmp/log4j.xml \
//   it/sissa/medialab/pdfimages/ReplaceBigImages \
//   --scale=XXX -v \
//   pesky-file.pdf


// CLASSPATH
// ---------

// This script uses pdfbox, picocli (for the command line), commons-io, commons-logging and log4j
// So the CLASSPATH could be:

// export CLASSPATH=$HOME/.m2/repository/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox/2.0.14/pdfbox-2.0.14.jar:$HOME/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2/commons-logging-1.2.jar:$HOME/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.6/commons-io-2.6.jar:$HOME/.m2/repository/info/picocli/picocli/3.9.5/picocli-3.9.5.jar:$HOME/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-api/2.11.2/log4j-api-2.11.2.jar:$HOME/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-core/2.11.2/log4j-core-2.11.2.jar:$HOME/typeset/scripts/pdfimages/target/classes/


// log4j.xml (example)
//
// <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
// <Configuration status="info" strict="true" name="XMLConfigTest" packages="org.apache.logging.log4j.test">

// <Appenders>
//   <Appender type="Console" name="STDOUT">
//     <Layout type="PatternLayout" pattern="%-5p %c{1}:%L %M - %m%n"/>
//   </Appender>
// </Appenders>

// <Loggers>
//   <Logger name="pippo"
//           level="info"
//           additivity="false">
//     <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
//   </Logger>

//   <Root level="info">
//     <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
//   </Root>
// </Loggers>

// </Configuration>


// export CLASSPATH=$HOME/.m2/repository/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox/2.0.14/pdfbox-2.0.14.jar:$HOME/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2/commons-logging-1.2.jar:$HOME/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.6/commons-io-2.6.jar:$HOME/.m2/repository/info/picocli/picocli/3.9.5/picocli-3.9.5.jar:$HOME/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-api/2.11.2/log4j-api-2.11.2.jar:$HOME/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-core/2.11.2/log4j-core-2.11.2.jar:./target/classes

// java -Dlog4j.configurationFile=log4j.xml it/sissa/medialab/pdfimages/ReplaceBigImages  --max=220 --min=200 -v --target=220  src/resources/META-INF/test-files/d.pdf


import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configurator;
import org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine;
import org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.DrawObject;
import org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.Operator;
import org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.state.Concatenate;
import org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.state.Restore;
import org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.state.Save;
import org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.state.SetGraphicsStateParameters;
import org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.state.SetMatrix;
import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSBase;
import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSName;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFStreamParser;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.ContentStreamWriter;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDResources;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.PDXObject;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.color.PDDeviceGray;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.form.PDFormXObject;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.LosslessFactory;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.PDImage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.PDImageXObject;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.PDInlineImage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.util.Matrix;

import picocli.CommandLine;
import picocli.CommandLine.Command;
import picocli.CommandLine.Option;
import picocli.CommandLine.Parameters;


@Command(description = "Resample raster images in the given pdf file when their resolution is outside the given min-max range.",
         name = "pdfimage",
         mixinStandardHelpOptions = true,
         version = "pdfimages 1.2")
         public class ReplaceBigImages
    extends PDFStreamEngine
    implements Runnable
{
    //    private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(ReplaceBigImages.class);
    private static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(ReplaceBigImages.class);

    public boolean hasInlineImages = false;
    public LinkedBlockingQueue<Matrix> tms = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Matrix>();

    @Parameters(paramLabel = "FILE", description = "File to process.")
    private File inputFile;

    @Option(names = "--min", description = "Resolution lower bound; defaults to 150", required = false)
    private float min_res=150;

    @Option(names = "--max", description = "Resolution upper bound; defaults to 220", required = false)
    private float max_res=220;

    @Option(names = "--target", description = "Desired resolution (only if the current resolution exeedes the bounds). Defaults to 220", required = false)
    private int desiredResolution = 220;

    @Option(names = "--scale", description = "Scale factor. The options min, max and target will be multiplied by this factor. This should be the same scale at which the pdf \"image\" under analysis will be included by the tex file into the final pdf. See 00-readme.txt. Defaults to 1.0", required = false)
    private float scale=1;

    @Option(names = { "-v", "--verbose" }, description = "Be verbose.")
    private boolean verbose = false;

    private int myCounter = 0;

    public ReplaceBigImages() throws IOException
    {
        addOperator(new Concatenate());
        addOperator(new DrawObject());
        addOperator(new SetGraphicsStateParameters());
        addOperator(new Save());
        addOperator(new Restore());
        addOperator(new SetMatrix());
    }

    @Override
    public void run()  {

        if (verbose) {
            if (log instanceof Logger) {

                // https://stackoverflow.com/a/44678752/1581629
                Configurator.setLevel(LogManager.getLogger(ReplaceBigImages.class).getName(), Level.DEBUG);
            } else {
                log.warn("Unknown logger " + log.getClass().toString() + "; ignoring option \"verbose\".");
                log.warn("I only know about " + Logger.class.toString());
            }
        }

        min_res = (float) (min_res * scale);
        max_res = (float) (max_res * scale);
        desiredResolution = (int) (desiredResolution * scale);

        try {
            document = PDDocument.load(inputFile);

            int pageNum = 0;
            for (PDPage page : document.getPages()) {
                pageNum++;
                log.info("Processing page: " + pageNum);
                processPage(page);
                if (hasInlineImages) {
                    replaceInlineImages(document, page, tms.remove());
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e);
        } finally {
            if (document != null) {
                log.debug("Ready to save");
                try {
                    document.save(inputFile.toPath().toString().replace(".pdf", "-m.pdf"));
                    log.debug("Document saved");
                    document.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static PDDocument document;

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException
    {
        ReplaceBigImages app = new ReplaceBigImages();
        CommandLine.run(app, args);
    }

    protected void processOperator( Operator operator, List<COSBase> operands) throws IOException
    {
        String operation = operator.getName();
        if( "Do".equals(operation) ) {
            log.debug("### Found Do operator");
            COSName objectName = (COSName) operands.get( 0 );
            PDXObject xobject = getResources().getXObject( objectName );

            if( xobject instanceof PDImageXObject)
            {
                log.debug(String.format("Looking at %s (%s)", objectName.getName(), xobject));
                PDImageXObject image = (PDImageXObject)xobject;
                Matrix ctmNew = getGraphicsState().getCurrentTransformationMatrix();
                BufferedImage scaledImage = changeImageResolution(image, ctmNew);
                if (scaledImage != null) {
                    log.debug(String.format("Replacing with %s", scaledImage));
                    PDImageXObject replacement_img = LosslessFactory.createFromImage(document, scaledImage);
                    replacement_img.setStencil(image.isStencil());
                    PDPage currentPage = getCurrentPage();
                    PDResources resources = currentPage.getResources();
                    resources.put(objectName, replacement_img);
                }

            } else if(xobject instanceof PDFormXObject)
            {
                PDFormXObject form = (PDFormXObject)xobject;
                showForm(form);
            }
        } else if  ("BI".equals(operation)) {
            hasInlineImages = true;
            // save the current transformation matrix
            // I will need it later, to compute the resolution of the inline image
            Matrix ctmNew = getGraphicsState().getCurrentTransformationMatrix();
            tms.add(ctmNew);
        } else {
            super.processOperator( operator, operands);
        }
    }


    protected void replaceInlineImages (PDDocument document, PDPage page, Matrix ctm) throws Exception {
        // take the content stream of the current page,
        // parse it, get a list of tokens
        // run through the list of tokens
        // and build a new list
        // when a BI operator is found,
        // change the resolution of the relative inline image
        // and replace the "BI" operator with the new one
        PDFStreamParser parser = new PDFStreamParser(page);
        parser.parse();
        List<Object> tokens = parser.getTokens();
        List<Object> newTokens = new ArrayList<Object>();
        for(int j=0; j<tokens.size(); j++) {
            Object token = tokens.get( j );

            if( token instanceof Operator ) {
                Operator operator = (Operator)token;
                if("BI".equals(operator.getName())) {
                    log.debug("### Found BI operator");
                    // NB: there is not trace of ID or EI operators in the original token list
                    //     so just replacing the BI should replace the whole block BI-ID-EI
                    PDResources resources = page.getResources();
                    PDInlineImage image = new PDInlineImage(operator.getImageParameters(),
                                                            operator.getImageData(),
                                                            resources);
                    BufferedImage scaledImage = changeImageResolution(image, ctm);

                    if (scaledImage != null) {
                        log.debug(String.format("Replacing with %s", scaledImage));
                        PDImageXObject helper_img = LosslessFactory.createFromImage(document, scaledImage);
                        helper_img.setStencil(image.isStencil());

                        InputStream img_data_stream = helper_img.getCOSObject().createRawInputStream();
                        byte [] img_data = IOUtils.toByteArray(img_data_stream);
                        img_data_stream.close();

                        Operator newBIoperator = Operator.getOperator("BI");

                        newBIoperator.setImageParameters(helper_img.getCOSObject());
                        newBIoperator.setImageData(img_data);

                        newTokens.add(newBIoperator);
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }
            newTokens.add( token );
        }

        // use newTokens to build a new stream
        PDStream newContents = new PDStream( document );
        OutputStream outputStream = newContents.createOutputStream();
        ContentStreamWriter writer = new ContentStreamWriter( outputStream );
        writer.writeTokens( newTokens );
        page.setContents( newContents );
        outputStream.close();
        log.debug("New contents set for page");
    }

    protected BufferedImage changeImageResolution( PDImage image, Matrix ctmNew)
        throws IOException
    {
        int imageWidth = image.getWidth();
        int imageHeight = image.getHeight();

        float imageXScale = Math.abs(ctmNew.getScalingFactorX());
        float imageYScale = Math.abs(ctmNew.getScalingFactorY());

        float resolution = imageWidth / (imageXScale / 72);

        int bufferedImageType = BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB;
        String stencil = "";
        if (image.isStencil()) {
            stencil = " (stencil)";
            bufferedImageType = BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY;
        } else if (image.getColorSpace() == PDDeviceGray.INSTANCE)  {
            bufferedImageType = BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY;
        }

        // TODO: take into consideration the size at which this file is included by TeX
        log.debug("Original size: (" + imageWidth + "," + imageHeight + ")@scale(" + imageXScale + "," + imageYScale
                + "); resolution = (" + min_res + "<)" + resolution + "(<" + max_res + ")" + stencil);

        if (resolution > max_res || resolution < min_res) {

            BufferedImage bImage = new BufferedImage(imageWidth, imageHeight, bufferedImageType);
            bImage.setData(image.getImage().getData());
            // do not do "bImage = image.getImage()" or the image type will be wrong

            if (image.isStencil()) {
                log.warn("Image is stencil, plese check.");
                // bImage = image.getStencilImage(Color.red);
                // ↑ No: see https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/8d6477f6e057b83ab34655041045dc9e0288b4eeba6d65b52a92ab52@%3Cusers.pdfbox.apache.org%3E
            }
            if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                myCounter += 1;
                log.debug("Saving original img to \"original-"+myCounter+".png\"");
                File outputfile = new File("original-"+myCounter+".png");
                ImageIO.write(bImage, "png", outputfile);
            }

            if (desiredResolution == -1) {
                desiredResolution = (int) ((max_res + min_res) / 2.0);
            }
            float xFactor = (imageXScale / 72) * desiredResolution / imageWidth;
            float yFactor = (imageYScale / 72) * desiredResolution / imageHeight;
            log.info("Scaling x by factor " + xFactor + " (desired resolution is " + desiredResolution + ")");
            int dWidth = (int) (xFactor * imageWidth);
            int dHeight = (int) (yFactor * imageHeight);
            // the image type is from
            // https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.awt.image.
            log.debug(String.format("Destination: %d x %d [%s]", dWidth, dHeight, bImage.getType()));
            BufferedImage scaledImage = new BufferedImage(dWidth, dHeight, bImage.getType());
            Graphics2D graphics2D = scaledImage.createGraphics();
            graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
            graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
            graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            graphics2D.drawImage(bImage, 0, 0, dWidth, dHeight, null);
            graphics2D.dispose();

            if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                log.debug("Saving scaled img to \"scaled-"+myCounter+".png\"");
                File outputfile = new File("scaled-"+myCounter+".png");
                ImageIO.write(scaledImage, "png", outputfile);
            }

            return scaledImage;
        }
        return null;
    }


    /**
     * @return the hasInlineImages
     */
    public boolean isHasInlineImages() {
        return hasInlineImages;
    }

    /**
     * @param hasInlineImages the hasInlineImages to set
     */
    public void setHasInlineImages(boolean hasInlineImages) {
        this.hasInlineImages = hasInlineImages;
    }

    /**
     * @return the tms
     */
    public LinkedBlockingQueue<Matrix> getTms() {
        return tms;
    }

    /**
     * @param tms the tms to set
     */
    public void setTms(LinkedBlockingQueue<Matrix> tms) {
        this.tms = tms;
    }

}
```

Comment: This may work for inline images in the page contents but inline images in form Xobjects or patterns are not found by this.