# log4j: cannot set logging to DEBUG

Tags: java, log4j2

I am having a problem with log4j --- I am trying to set the logging level to DEBUG with a log4j.properties file.  I know that this partially works because another component (netty
) works but by the time it gets to me logging is set to ERROR and above.

Here is my log4j.properties file:

```
#Define root logger options
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, console

log4j.logger.com.ltsllc.miranda=DEBUG

#Define console appender

log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p %c{1} - %m%n
```

here is the code that checks the debugging level:

```
    if (l.isDebugEnabled()) {
        l.debug("DEBUG is enabled");
    } else {
        l.error ("Debug is disabled");
        l.error ("level is: " + l.getLevel());
    }
```

here is the output:

```
DEBUG ResourceLeakDetector - -Dio.netty.leakDetection.level: simple
DEBUG ResourceLeakDetector - -Dio.netty.leakDetection.targetRecords: 4
DEBUG ResourceLeakDetectorFactory - Loaded default ResourceLeakDetector: io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector@44b3606b
22:43:46.696 \[main\] ERROR com.ltsllc.miranda.Miranda - Debug is disabled
22:43:46.700 \[main\] ERROR com.ltsllc.miranda.Miranda - level is: ERROR
DEBUG DefaultChannelId - -Dio.netty.processId: 30572 (auto-detected)
DEBUG NetUtil - -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack: false
```

I expected something like this

```
DEGUG com.ltsllc.miranda.Miranda - DEBUG is enabled
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in a question relating to how to set the logging level programmatically:

```
LoggerContext ctx = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
Configuration config = ctx.getConfiguration();
LoggerConfig loggerConfig = config.getLoggerConfig(LogManager.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME); 
loggerConfig.setLevel(level);
ctx.updateLoggers();  // This causes all Loggers to refetch information from their LoggerConfig.
```

This was the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23434252/programmatically-change-log-level-in-log4j2)

Answer (score 1):

When no configuration is provided the Log4j2 Reference Implementation (`log4j-core`) uses a `%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n` pattern and an `ERROR` level. This is what you are observing on your standard output.

The logging APIs and backends are probably bound as follows:

- Netty's internal logging API (cf. [`InternalLoggerFactory`](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/common/src/main/java/io/netty/util/internal/logging/InternalLoggerFactory.java)) binds to SLF4J (`slf4j-api`), which uses Log4j 1.x or Reload4j as backend. This backend is the one you **configured**.
- the Log4j2 API you use in your code(cf. [API separation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/api-separation.html)) binds to Log4j2 Reference Implementation, which you **didn't configure**. I am guessing that the fully qualified class name of `l` in your code is `org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger`.

I am assuming you don't want to use Log4j 1.x as backend (it was declared end-of-life 8 years ago) so you need to:

1. Configure `log4j-core` by adding a `log4j2.xml` file with content:

   ```xml
   <Configuration>
     <Appenders>
       <Console name="console">
         <PatternLayout pattern="%-5p %c{1} - %m%n"/>
       </Console>
     </Appenders>
     <Loggers>
       <Root level="DEBUG">
         <AppenderRef ref="console"/>
       </Root>
     </Loggers>
   </Configuration>
   ```
2. Fix up your dependencies, by:

   - Removing the `log4j:log4j` and `ch.qos.reload4j:reload4j` artifacts from your classpath. This also includes the SLF4J bindings `org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12` and `org.slf4j:slf4j-reload4j`.
   - Netty binds to Log4j2 API if SLF4J (`slf4j-api`) is not present, but other libraries might be using SLF4J directly. If you are using Maven you need these 3 artifacts:

     ```xml
      <dependencyManagement>
        <!-- Add the BOM, so you don't need to specify version -->
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-bom</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.0</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </dependencyManagement>
      <dependencies>
        <!-- Used in your code -->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Only necessary at runtime -->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
          <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--
          ~ If some of your libraries use SLF4J API directly
          ~ bind them to `log4j-api`:
          -->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
          <!-- Replace with log4j-slf4j2-impl if SLF4J 2.x is used -->
          <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
          <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
     ```

     If your libraries use other logging APIs (e.g. Jakarta Apache Commons Logging, `java.util.logging`, JBoss Logging), you'll also need to bind them to `log4j-api`.

**Edit**: I would advise against using the properties configuration format for Log4j 2.x, since it is extremely verbose to store a tree-like structure in a flat format. Besides when Log4j 1.x was released the JRE did not have an XML parser, now it has it.

The XML configuration above can be translated to properties as:

```
appender.0.type = Console
appender.0.name = console
appender.0.0.type = PatternLayout
appender.0.0.pattern = %-5p %c{1} - %m%n

logger.rootLogger.level = DEBUG
logger.rootLogger.appenderRef.0.ref = console
##
# The `rootLogger` config can be abbreviated in recent versions to
#   logger.rootLogger = DEBUG, console
```

Comment: My maven could not find log4j-slf4j2-impl.  Please let me know what (which version of maven) you tried this with.

Comment: Also --- could you restate the changes in log4j.xml as properties for log4j.properties?

Comment: @ClarkHobbie: `log4j-slf4j2-impl` is available since version 2.19.0 (cf. [MvnRepository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-slf4j2-impl)) (first version after the release of SLF4J 2.x).

Comment: I added a properties configuration to the answer. Remark that the autodetected configuration files in Log4j 2.x must start with `log4j2` (notice the 2): `log4j2.xml` or `log4j2.properties`.

Comment: The version of maven that comes with IDEA cannont resolve this dependency:  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <!-- Replace with log4j-slf4j2-impl if SLF4J 2.x is used -->
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency> I integrated your other changes and it still doesn't work.

Comment: I tried, but it could not resolve the dependency when I tried to add maven central as a repository.