# Listing all active Loggers in Google AppEngine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, logging

Is there a way in Java AppEngine to list all the active Loggers?

I'd like to create a JSP to batch edit the log levels of all current loggers, without deploying any files.

The problem is that `LogManager` class is not supported in GAE, so all [these examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169578/number-of-loggers-used) are not useful

Any ideas?

Comment: Good question.  I'd like to find the system logger in dev console and change its handlers so it doesn't print everything in red!

Comment: Turns out that the system logger on dev console is name "" (empty string).  So it can be changed with Logger.getLogger("") and then removing its handlers and adding your own.

Comment: It is interesting that java.util.logging.LoggingMXBean is listed in the [JRE class whitelist](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist) but there is no way to gain a reference to an object that implements that interface.  LogManger and java.lang.management are blocked.