# Java Quartz Scheduler turning off logging

Tags: java, logging, console, quartz-scheduler

My java console is being bombarded with messages and I want to turn this off.

my code is

```
    List<Logger> loggers = Collections.<Logger>list(LogManager.getCurrentLoggers());
        loggers.add(LogManager.getLogger(<<something goes here>>));
        for (Logger logger : loggers) {
            logger.setLevel(Level.OFF);
        }
```

Is this code right, I don't know how to setup the alternative which is Log4j.properties.

Anyway the code will likely turn off all loggers, how do I turn off
Log4j (i.e. quartz scheduler)

Any help??

Comment: Seems like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169578/number-of-loggers-used, maybe you might try first?

Comment: I tried getRootLogger() but my application does not pick this up

Comment: Soz this might defeat the purpose, I only want to turn off quartz scheduler log

Comment: put log4j properties in classpath, i.e. check this example http://www.mkyong.com/logging/log4j-hello-world-example/ and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297686/log4j-package-specific-logging you need something like "log4j.logger.org.quartz=OFF"

Comment: Ok giger, I make a log4j.properties in my project class path and I add log4j.logger.org.quartz=OFF is this correct?   Just to clarify 1 line.

Comment: No it should be something like MKyong example

Comment: At least rootLogger an stdout parts should be there then additionally you add ..org.quartz=off which means turn off all loggers under this package

Comment: OK I add log4j.logger.org.quartz=OFF in log4j.properties

Comment: It says I do not have access to this file  java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\log4j-application.log (Access is denied)

Comment: yes because file appender trying to create this log file in system, it is defined in your properties file, so what you can do is remove all the lines starting with "log4j.appender.file" and update root logger as log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout

Comment: I've taken out the log4j.appender.filefile and added log4j.logger.org.quartz=OFF but I'm still getting alot of print outs